# Why diamonds are only defined in characteristic $p$?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-spaces, perfectoid-spaces

I'm trying to read Scholze's article "*Etale cohomology of diamonds*" ([arXiv link](https://arxiv.org/abs/1709.07343)) and both in this article and in Berkeley notes, the diamonds are defined as sheaves on the category of characteristic $p$ perfectoid spaces that can be written as a quotient of a perfectoid space by a proetale equivalence relation. What I don't understand is that why can't define diamonds over the whole category of perfectoid spaces (or at least perfectoid space over a base $S$).

Are there some important properties of diamonds that only work over characteristic $p$ or is this because we only need diamond in characteristic $p$ case?

Comment: Defining them in characteristic $p$ gives more flexibility (e.g. the existence of absolute products). All the other options you mentioned can be realized in this framework too. (Hint: The category of all perfectoid spaces is equivalent to the slice $\mathrm{Perf}_{ / \mathrm{Spd}\mathbf{Z}_p}$.)